# NLog.config seems not to be taken into account

Tags: c#, xml, logging, configuration, nlog

I would like to modify my `NLog` configuration, but I have the impression that my modifications are not taken into account.

According to [this URL](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations), the `NLog` configuration can be found:

1. In the file `applicationname.exe.config`. In my case, this file only contains the following `NLog` related lines:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="Modules" />
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
   ```
2. `applicationname.exe.nlog` in application’s directory (there is no such file).
3. `NLog.config` in application’s directory. This file exists and contains the following entries:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
        <targets>
          <target name="logfile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
            <target xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate} | ${threadid} | ${logger} | ${message} ..." fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.tralala.${level}.log" />
          </target>
          <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
        </targets>
   ```

The way the logger is loaded in the application is as follows:

```
using NLog;
...
private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

My logfiles are always of the form `"${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.log"` instead of the mentioned `"${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.tralala.${level}.log"`, so I have the impression my `NLog.config` file is not taken into account (or I'm working with the wrong target).

Which one is it and how can I work in order to be able to take my configuration into account?

Oh, for your information, I'm working on a Windows-10 computer, this is the name of my `NLog.config` file as shown in my Linux subsystem (in order to ensure the case sensitivity):

```
WSL Linux Prompt> ls -ltra | grep "NLog.config"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user group     742 Mar  3 13:22 NLog.config
```

**Edit:**
By the way: is there a way to configure `NLog` in order to start every logging session with some information about the used configuration?

**Edit: internal log results:**
When I enable internal logging, this is what I get:

```
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Targets for Test by level:
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Trace =>
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Debug => Console LogFile Other_Application
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Info => Console LogFile Other_Application
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Warn => Console LogFile Other_Application
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Error => Console LogFile Other_Application
2022-03-17 10:25:52.8775 Debug Fatal => Console LogFile Other_Application
```

As you can see, no `filePath` or so, I have no idea where `NLog` gets its configuration from.

Comment: You can activate the NLog InternalLogger if you are uncertain of where NLog-config is loaded from: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging#example-with-internal-logging-from-code (Just make sure to enable the InternalLogger before creating the first NLog-Logger)

Comment: If you execute `NLog.LogManager.Configuration?.ToString()` then it should include the path of the loaded `NLog.config`. Ex. `Logger.Info("NLog Config {0}", NLog.LogManager.Configuration)`.

Comment: @RolfKristensen: I like your approach, but we're not there yet: I have put `NLog.LogManager.Configuration?.ToString()` in the immediate window and what I see is this: `"TargetNames=Console, LogFile, Application_Name, ConfigItems=28"`, so it reads the content of the configuration file(s), but it does not mention where that configuration file or files is or are located.

Comment: The extra output was [added with NLog 4.7.1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3884), so if using latest version of NLog and you don't see the `FilePath=` in the output, then it is probably because the NLog configuration is not loaded from file. But created from code. Maybe [activate NLog InternalLogger from code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging#example-with-internal-logging-from-code), and look for clues.

Comment: @RolfKristensen: I've updated my question after having added internal logging. As you can see, no `FilePath` entry in the results, so I have the impression that the `NLog.config` is not taken into account. How can I enforce that file being taken into account?

Comment: I think you are activating the NLog InternalLogger too late, so all initialization and loading already has completed. You must activate NLog InternalLogger before creating the first NLog-Logger object (including any `private static Logger` objects). But you can always explicit load NLog-configuration with `NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile()`

Comment: @RolfKristensen: I'm sorry, but when I launch the `NLog.....LoadConfigurationFromFile()` method, then I get this exception: `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'NLog.Config.ISetupBuilder NLog.LogManager.Setup()'.`. For your information, I'm working with `NLog` version 4.5.4.

Comment: You can try `LogManager.LoadConfiguration(...)` when older version of NLog. Though that method has been made obsolete with NLog v5, to prepare for the future NLog v6.